# How can I configure a link to be a normal link or an onclick handler?

Tags: jquery, html

I want to give the user the option to configure a link either as a normal link or with an onclick event. In case of the onclick event the default behaviour should be disabled. Currently I've this link:

```
  <a target="_blank" class="arrow" href="javascript:void();" onclick="f(\"value",\"value\");return false;">
```

This works great for the onclick event. But how is the link supposed to be looking when I only need the href?

This?:

```
<a target="_blank" class="arrow" href="http://www.xy.com" onclick="return false;">
```

Or it's better to remove the onclick attribute completely? Or is this better:

```
 <a target="_blank" class="arrow" href="http://www.xy.com" onclick="javascript:void();">
```

Comment: How are you giving people the choice of how the link works?

Comment: If you're attaching an event handler, completely remove the `onclick` attribute. It is not needed.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use onclick. Attach a click handler, where a boolean flag depends on the user's choice.

```
$('#yourLink').on('click', function(){
    //this value depends on the user's choice.
    var doesUserWantHref = true;

    if (doesUserWantHref) {
        //do nothing
        return true;
    } else {
        //you js logic goes here
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Problem is that I use the jquery template plugin and I feed it with my data from my ajax function hence the href and the onclick is already present and must be replaced?

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this after page load by doing something like...

```
// for just the href
$("#yourLink").attr("href", "http://yourlink.com/").on("click", function() { });
```

or

```
// for just the onclick
$("#yourLink").attr("href", "javascript: void()").on("click", function() { /* useful work */ });
```